# Regex to match separate integer list in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match comma separate integer list using Regex. I have used bellow pattern but it doesn't work for me.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox_ImportRowsList.Text, @"^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+))*"))
{
        errorProvider1.SetError(label_ListRowPosttext, "Row Count invalid!");
}
```

**Valid Inputs:**

```
1
1,2
1,4,6,10
```

**Invalid Inputs:**

```
1,
1.1
1,A
2,/,1
,1,3
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work for me' - so which of your example inputs does it get wrong?

Comment: If you just want integers as a result why not use `Int32.TryParse()` and then `string.Split(",")` to separate the values?

Comment: try out my edited regx in my answer...

Comment: hi, check my edit answer that might help you to resolve your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the asterisk in the wrong place.  Instead of this:

```
@"^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+))*"
```

...use this:

```
@"^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)"
```

Additionally, you should anchor the end like you did the beginning, and don't really need the outermost set of parentheses:

```
@"^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$"
```

Answer (score 3):

use this regular expression:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Best way to validate your comma separated string is

```
string someString = "1,2,3"; 


bool myResults = someString.Split(';').
       Any<string>(s => !isNumeric(s)); 
if(myResults)
  Console.Writeln("invalid number");
else
  Console.Writeln("valid number");


public bool isNumeric(string val)
{
    if(val == String.Empty)
      return false;       
    int result;
    return int.TryParse(val,out result);
}
```

---

The following might also work for you. This regex will also capture an empty string.

```
^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$
```

or

```
 ^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

- start with an integer, so '\d+'. That is 1 or more digit characters ('0'-'9')
- Then make a set of parenthesis which contains ',\d+' and put an asterisk after it. allow the , and digit

Comment: Any of this solutions not work for me. it does not match the pattern. :(

Comment: +1.  But I'd change your Linq statement to use `Any` like this... `return !text.Split(',').Any<string>(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || !isNumeric(s));`  There's no point in going through the whole array, and `Any` stops after it finds the first invalid entry.

Comment: And actually, checking for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` isn't necessary since `int.TryParse` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^\d+(,\d+)*$` but as @Lazarus has pointed out, this may be a case where regex is a bit of a overkill and `string.Split()` would be better utilized you could even use this with a `int.tryParse` if you are trying to manipulate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("1");
            list.Add("1.1");
            list.Add("1,A");
            list.Add("2,/,1");


            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^([0-9](,[0-9])*)$"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no match :" + item);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
String strInput = textBox_ImportRowsList.Text;
foreach (String s in strInput.Split(new[]{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    if(!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+(,\d+)*$"))
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(label_ListRowPosttext, "Row Count invalid!");    
    }
}
```